# Boost, inserting static library in repository

Tags: c++, git, boost, static-libraries

I'm working on a large project, cross platform between Linux and OSx. 
I'm would like to include boost functionalities, but I don't want to force all the the collaborators to install on their machine (with totally different environment) all the boost libraries.

If I compile boost on my machine, and put the static libraries inside the repository, which problem could I face? Can my colleagues use the same static libraries on their environment?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there will be difference. The static libraries are not the same on OS X and Linux. Also compilation depends on toolset (see [boost guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#identify-your-toolset)). And there can be issues if IDEs are different.

However you can compile both versions from one platform (see [Cross-compilation](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html)) and put them in repository, but putting binary objects is not the best idea (even if they don't depend on platform).

I think you could try to compile and link boost on different platforms, maybe you will succeed, but you can not cover all the scenarios for sure. It is better to create boost compilation script and tell everyone to use it.